# Make input line not print if i exit loop (i.e. How do I avoid the blank "Item:" line before my total?)

Tags: python, cs50

How do I avoid the blank "Item:" line before my total?

```
menu ={"Baja Taco": 4.00,
    "Burrito": 7.50,
    "Bowl": 8.50,
    "Nachos": 11.00,
    "Quesadilla": 8.50,
    "Super Burrito": 8.50,
    "Super Quesadilla": 9.50,
    "Taco": 3.00,
    "Tortilla Salad": 8.00}

def main():
    price = getprice()
    print("\n${0:.2f}".format(price))

def getprice():
    price = 0
    while True:
        try:
            item = input("Item: ").replace("Item: ","").title()
            if item in menu:
                price = price + int(menu[item])
            elif KeyError:
                item = input("Item: ").replace("Item: ","").title()
                price = price + int(menu[item])
        except EOFError:
            break
    return price
main()
```

---

terminal window

Item: taco

Item: taco

Item: tortilla salad

Item:

$14.00

Comment: What's the point of the `.replace` in `input("Item: ").replace("Item: ","")`? The string returned by `input` doesn't include the prompt

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand how you expect this to work. It seems like you want the program not to print the `Item:` text, if the input item isn't found in the `menu`. But that text is a **prompt for** the input item. How can the program know that the user will input an empty line, *before the user actually does that*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It only breaks on EOF, so you could `Ctrl-D` on the last item you type to break without printing an extra "Item:" line

Comment: `if ... elif KeyError` is nonsensical. You catch errors using a `try..except` block. Your code works by a happy accident in that the type `KeyError` is truthy, so whenever it reaches that `elif` it always enters that block. You want to either `try`  adding to `price` without checking if `item in menu` and catch the `KeyError`, or you want an `if item in menu: ... else: ...`

Comment: @Dash did you try it? At least on my terminal, ctrl-D only works at the beginning of a line, when using line-buffered input (as in the `input` function in Python). When I was on Windows, I observed ctrl-Z to work the same way.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel ah, I guess the pycharm run window handles the input a little differently

Comment: can you please clarify the question since the "terminal window" output does not look like the [demo from the spec](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/3/taqueria/#demo), ie does not conform to the spec "_After each inputted item, display the total cost of all items inputted thus far,_"